# npm can't install global packages?

Tags: javascript, npm, gulp, node-modules

Alright, Im just trying to install gulp-cli globally. At first I tried `npm install --global gulp-cli` and got many errors, the first being a permissions error

> Missing write access to
> /Users/myusername/.npm-global/lib/node_modules/gulp-cli

So I tried `sudo chown -R $USER /usr/local/lib/node_modules`, did nothing.

Next I tried `sudo npm install gulp-cli -g`, which says it installed gulp-cli, but when I try `gulp -v` I get bash: no command found:

[image]

How can I fix this and install gulp globally?

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend you bundle `gulp` and `gulp-cli` in your package.json and use them via `npx` which will allow you to skip the global installation altogether and keep your project self-contained. To do this you can install the packages as you normally would in your project:

```
npm install --save-dev gulp gulp-cli
```

and then from **within your project directory** you can do

```
npx gulp
```

This will find the binary in your local node_modules, remove the need for the global installation (and the admin rights), and keep your task runner version up to date with your project dependencies.